# Quantile function and empty set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

We define the set of quantiles as:

Let $F$ be a distribution function for a probability $P$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{B}))$. Let $0<p<1$. Then

$$Q(p)=\{x\in \mathbb{R} | F(x-)\leq p \leq F(x)\}$$
to be a $p$-quantile of $P$ (or $F$) and $x\in Q$ is said to be a $p$-quantile.

---

**Let $F$ be a distribution for a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{B}))$. Show that $Q(p)\neq\emptyset$**

---

I am quite new to measure theory and its applications on probability theory. I know that intuitively this result makes sense since $0<p<1$ and from my (very basic) understanding the quantile is basically quantiles are cut points dividing the range of a probability distribution into continuous intervals with equal probabilities.
However, showing this is far beyond my capabilities. How would this be proven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sketch**
Look at $T=\{t | F(t) \geq p\}$. Observe that this is a closed interval of the form $[q,\infty)$ where $q$ is the inf over the aforementioned set.

You might question the inclusion of $q$ in the interval. Look at $F(q +{1/n})$ and recall that $F$ is right cts to show that $q$  is indeed included.

Now show that $q$ is the element you seek. Hint: take $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  with $x_n\uparrow q$ (like for instance $x_n=q-\frac{1}{n}$) and look at $F(x_n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

**Proof:**
Let $T=\{t | F(t) \geq p\}$. If $t \in T$ then $t'>t \implies t' \in T$ since $F$ is non-decreasing.  Since $F(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow -\infty$ there is some $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(r) \leq p\in (0,1)$. So $\inf{T}>-\infty$.
Set $q=\inf{T}$. Then by the greatest lower bound property: $q+1/n \in T$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus we have $p \leq F(q+1/n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If it is true for *every* $n$, then it remains true in the limit. That is (here we use right-cts);

$$p\leq F(q)$$

We want to show $F(q^-)\leq p$. Because $q$ is a lower bound for $T$, $q-1/m \notin T$ for any $m$. So $F(q-1/m)\leq p$ for *every* $m$. Now $F(q-1/m)\rightarrow F(q^-)$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$. So (as before) $$F(q^-)\leq p$$
Putting the two inequalities togther yields;
$$F(q^-)\leq p \leq F(q)$$ so that $q \in Q(p)$
and we are done.

Comment: I am not quite sure on why we are considering the set in the start and what the approach is. I know - as you said - that it is right cts. But why do I have to look at that set?

Comment: The hint does not explain it for me, though, the limit is obvious

Comment: My approach is to reverse-engineer the quantile function (which you will learn is precisely the $q$ in my response). I will add details to make the proof more readable.

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment is imprecise - the quantile function is not $''q''$ but rather is a function on $(0,1)$ wich takes $p \mapsto \inf\{t | F(t)\geq p}$. It is essentially the ''inverse'' of your CDF.

Comment: but why does showing $F(q-)\leq p$ show that $Q(p)$ is never equal to the empty set?

Comment: You want to show that your set $Q(p)$ is not the empty set. That is - it has at least one element. We constructed such an element - q.

Comment: I get it now, thanks!